# Makefile:recipe for target failed when using -j option

Tags: python, makefile, parallel-processing

*

I have a problem with my make process or file when I try to run the make with more than one process.
`make -j 2` (any number larger than 1 causes my make process to finish with followin error message)

```
Makefile:117: recipe for target '...' failed
make: *** [...] Error 134
```

The make process is running through smoothly, when I do not use the option `-j` (or use `-j 1`)

```
$ make 10
python3 SequencePrediction.py ACAM 2>/dev/null
Start SequencePrediction on 'ACAM'
Finished SequencePrediction on 'ACAM' in 325.40s
python3 SequencePrediction.py ACC 2>/dev/null
Start SequencePrediction on 'ACC'
...
```

When I use -j option make will terminate with the above mentioned error

```
$ make 10 -j 10
python3 SequencePrediction.py ACAM 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py ACC 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py ALJJ 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py APTX 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py AQN 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py ARII 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py ARTL 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py BBIO 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py BLNKW 2>/dev/null
python3 SequencePrediction.py BNKD 2>/dev/null
Start SequencePrediction on 'BBIO'
Start SequencePrediction on 'ARTL'
Start SequencePrediction on 'APTX'
Start SequencePrediction on 'ALJJ'
Start SequencePrediction on 'BNKD'
Start SequencePrediction on 'ARII'
Start SequencePrediction on 'ACC'
Start SequencePrediction on 'BLNKW'
Finished SequencePrediction on 'BLNKW' in 0.02s
Start SequencePrediction on 'ACAM'
Start SequencePrediction on 'AQN'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'BBIO' failed
make: *** [BBIO] Error 134
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'APTX' failed
make: *** [APTX] Error 134
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ARTL' failed
make: *** [ARTL] Error 134
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'BNKD' failed
make: *** [BNKD] Error 134
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ACAM' failed
make: *** [ACAM] Error 1
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ALJJ' failed
make: *** [ALJJ] Error 134
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'AQN' failed
make: *** [AQN] Error 1
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ARII' failed
make: *** [ARII] Error 1
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ACC' failed
make: *** [ACC] Error 1
```

My makefile is quite simple, so I would appreciate if somebody can help me getting the parallel execution of make running (will save me a lot of computation time)

```
.PHONY: 100 10

10: ACAM \
    ACC \
    ALJJ \
    APTX \
    AQN \
    ARII \
    ARTL \
    BBIO \
    BLNKW \
    BNKD

100:    ACAM \
    ACC \
    ALJJ \
    APTX \
    AQN \
    ARII \
    ARTL \
    BBIO \
    BLNKW \
    BNKD \
    BVSN \
    ... many more


%:
    python3 SequencePrediction.py $@ 2>/dev/null
```

This is line 117 in the Makefile

```
    python3 SequencePrediction.py $@ 2>/dev/null
```

Thanks in advance for helping answers

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that would cause the problem.  What does `SequencePrediction.py` do?  Can you show the code?

Comment: SequencePrediction.py is quite long, but I do not think this causes the problem. In single process mode it is running.
But I will try to search for a reaction, when changing the python code

Comment: Note that SequencePrediction.py will be run in parallel and should support that: if it generate temporary files, they should not be the same because otherwise it will fail

Comment: G.M.You are right! It seems that there is an issue in the python code behind.
Thanks for giving me the missing hint

Comment: Ok, now I found the issue. Somehow the tensorflow GPU version was installed and then only one process can run. Before I had the CPU version installed, where everything was running smoothly in parallel.

Thanks anyhow!

Sometimes it is just enough to talk about the problem, then the solution will come alone..